# How to stop date when someone dies

Tags: date, ms-access

I have an access database for my dairy farm. I have one field named `DateBorn`, a module function `fAge`, and an unbound field named `AgeNow`. For this I have the expression:

```
=IIf(IsNull([DateBorn]),"",fAge([DateBorn]),Date()))
```

With this expression, whenever I type in a value for `DateBorn`, it calculates age for me in years, months, and days. It has worked fine thus far.

Now I want to add something to it; another field named `DateDied`. I want an expression that whenever I put `DateDied`, it should stop calculating age for that particular record.

Comment: You need to add a second `Iff` Check If field `DateDied` is null. If true, then return the value of `Date()`. If false, then means it died, make it return the death date so the age will be always the same

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you made a mistake in your sample regarding calling the function `fAge()`.

I expect it needs two date parameters.

That expression always calculates the age, but for people who died it uses `DateDied` instead of `Date()`:

```
=IIf(IsNull([DateBorn]),"",fAge([DateBorn],NZ([DateDied],Date())))
```

If in case of dead people there shouldn't be any calculated age use this:

```
=IIf(IsNull([DateBorn]) Or Not IsNull([DateDied]),"",fAge([DateBorn],Date()))
```

Comment: Thanks. the above expression worked fine for me. This database is for my dairy farm. When calf is born or died. I have to keep records. Thanks alot for your help